# PHP passing string over url encode data

Tags: javascript, php, decode, encode

i use PHP file to send data from my web to JS. And i sending data to php by URL. For xample. www.web.com/send.php?data=Hello everybody. And my problem is, if someone send special character or emoticon, PHP script wont work. Is there any function to encode string to string only with letters and numbers, and on PHP side decode it? Thanks, for replyes ;).

Comment: If you use a form, that is done automatically. How / where is your url generated?

Comment: javascript [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and PHP [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript use:

```
encodeURIComponent('Hello everybody')
```

In PHP use:

```
$data=$_GET['data'];
```

Comment: The contents of the `$_GET` superglobal are already percent-decoded.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you should use the following function to encode the url:

**var url = 'www.web.com/send.php?data='+encodeURIComponent('Hello everybody');**

in php you can use:

**$data = $_GET['data'];**

Answer (score 0):

I'am using these functions for decode/encode

```
public function encode($string)
    {

        $string=$string*1498158+825920496;
        return urlencode(base64_encode($string));

    }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public function decode($string)
    {
        $string=base64_decode(urldecode($string));
        $string=($string-825920496)/1498158;
        return  $string;
    }
```